# Moving localRepository to another computer downloads too much

Tags: maven

I run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` on my mac and build success.I have a server and want to build project on that.But it has poor internet speed.So I move the localRepository on my mac to the server.The version of Java and Maven is the same.And also run `mvn clean package -DskipTests`.But it still need to Download so much things.I wonder why and what to do so I can package project on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to download all the dependencies that are defined in the pom.xml as you are building the project again with "mvn ... package".

If you want to avoid this situation, you could just transfer your generated artifacts to the server. This is you project/target/[project].jar or project/target/[project].war depending on your configuration.

Another option would be to publish your artifacts to a Maven repository. i.e. usually a private one.

Comment: Thanks are given by accepting the answer and voting it :)